# How to assign values to this array?

Tags: c#

New to SOAP. VS auto-generated a Reference.cs from a SOAP .wsdl file,

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("longID", Order=6)]
public Xmember[] longID
{
    get
    {
        return this.longIDField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.longIDField = value;
    }
}

public partial class Xmember
{
    private ulong longIDField;
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public ulong longID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.longIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.longIDField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

when I call and pass a value like

```
ulong myID = 123;
objXmember[0] = myID;
objXmember[1] = 0;
objXmember[2] = 0;
objXmember[3] = 0;
objXmember[4] = 0;
objXmember[5] = 0;
```

got

> "cannot implicitly convert type ulong to 'Xmember'"

Comment: When you assign a value to an element of an array, the value's type must match the type of the array's elements. See duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> New to SOAP. VS auto-generated

This has zero to do with soap and is a basic C# question.

> "cannot implicitly convert type ulong to 'Xmember'"

You try to assign numerig numbers to elements that are defined as being of type XMember. It tells you taht.

The code you provide says so itself:

> public Xmember[] longID

So, per basic C#, you must assign new elements of Xmember:

> objXmember[1] = new XMember() { longID = 123 }

The code may come from SOAP, but at the end you have a basic "assign item to array" problem that is pure C# syntax.